# jQplot dragable

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I'm using jQplot within jQuery and am trying to make the points dragable. jqplot has this functionality through the [jqplot.dragable plugin](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dragable-js.html#$.jqplot.Dragable)

I should say that I am new to jQplot, but I do have it plotting my information correctly.

I think that I am using the [dragability option](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html) correctly. (Use that link and find 'dragable:' to see an example), but something must be wrong in my code.

---

Here is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dragable.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.jqplot-axis {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 90%; 
}
.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip {
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    <?php 
        $series = "";

        $start = strtotime("Jan 1 2001 00:00:00");
        $end = strtotime("Dec 31 2001 00:00:00");
        for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 432000) {
            if ($i > $start) {
                $series .= ", ";
            }
            $series .= "['" . date("m/d/Y", $i) . " 00:00:00', 2]";
        }
    ?>

    var series = [<?php echo $series; ?>];

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('Chart1', [series], {
        seriesDefaults: {

        },
        series: [
            { label: 'Importance' }
        ],
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions: { formatString: '%b %e' },
                min: "12-27-2000 00:00:00",
                max: "12-31-2001 00:00:00",
                tickInterval: "15 days"
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: -10,
                max: 10
            }
        },
        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            showMarker: false,
            tooltipAxes: 'xy',
            formatString: '%s<br />%s'
        },
        dragable: {
            color: '#FF0000',
            constrainTo: 'none'
        }
    });

    var xaxis = $('.jqplot-axis.jqplot-xaxis div');
    xaxis.first().css('display', 'none');
    xaxis.last().css('display', 'none');
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='Chart1'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to find the answer. 'dragable' is not a configuration option in the base of the jqplot object. 'dragable' is a configuration option within a 'series'. Also, the series must have 'isDragable' set to true.

Here the modified code for the 'series' configuration option.

```
series: [
    {
        label: 'Importance',
        dragable: {
            color: undefined,
            constrainTo: 'y'
        },
        isDragable: true
    }
],
```

ref: [jqPlot options tutorial](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/optionsTutorial-txt.html)